# How to Calculate Profit and Loss for trading position?

Tags: trading, accounting, portfolio, profitability

On my homework problem. I have this scenario below:

- 12/10/2010 - Long Position in a stock of 800 shares at $4.5 per share.
- 12/10/2010 - Long Position in the same stock of 200 shares at $4.55 per share.
- 12/31/2010 - the price of the stock is $4.60/share
- 02/28/2011 - the price of the stock is  $4.58/share
- 03/16/2011 - the price of the stock is  $4.61/share

I was asked to calculate the YTD and MTD PnL for 16/03/2011.

For YTD 
I did the total position(800+200) times the price difference(4.61-4.60). But, not sure whether this is right way to calculate the PnL.

Comment: This question is a perfect fit for the Accounting site (currently a proposal in Area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113560/accounting?referrer=FNOG9_mXNYnhlAdnl9FE8w2 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Month to date**

For the month to date (MTD), the price on Feb 28th is $4.58 and the price on March 16th is $4.61 so the return is

```
(4.61 - 4.58) / 4.58 = 0.00655022 = 0.655022 %
```

which can be written more simply as

```
4.61 / 4.58 - 1 = 0.00655022 = 0.655022 %
```

The position is 1000 shares valued at $4580 on Feb 28th, so the profit on the month to date is

```
$4580 * 0.00655022 = $30
```

**Calendar year to date**

For the calendar year to date (YTD), the price on Dec 31st is $4.60 and the price on Feb 28th is $4.58 so the return to Feb 28th is

```
4.58 / 4.60 - 1 = -0.00434783 = -0.434783 %
```

The return from Feb 28th to March 16th is 0.655022 % so the year to date return is

```
(1 - 0.00434783) * (1 + 0.00655022) - 1 = 0.00217391 = 0.217391 %
```

or more directly

```
(4.58 / 4.60) * (4.61 / 4.58) - 1 = 0.00217391 = 0.217391 %
```

So the 2011 YTD profit on 1000 shares valued at $4600 on Dec 31st is

```
$4600 * 0.00217391 = $10
```

**Year to date starting Dec 10th**

For the year to date starting Dec 10th, the starting value is

```
800 * $4.50 + 200 * $4.55 = $4510
```

and the value on Dec 31st is `1000 * $4.60 = $4600`

so the return is `$4600 / $4510 - 1 = 0.0199557 = 1.99557 %`

The year to date profit is therefore

```
$4510 * ((4.6 / 4.51) * (4.58 / 4.60) * (4.61 / 4.58) - 1) = $100
```

Note - YTD is often understood to mean calendar year to date.  To cover all the bases state both, ie "*calendar YTD (2011)*" and "*YTD starting Dec 10th 2010*".

**Edit further to comment**

For the calendar year to date, with 200 shares sold on Jan 10th with the share price at $4.58, the return from Dec 31st to Jan 10th is

```
4.58 / 4.60 - 1 = -0.00434783 = -0.434783 %
```

The return from Jan 10th to Feb 28th is

```
4.58 / 4.58 - 1 = 0
```

The return from Feb 28th to March 16th is

```
4.61 / 4.58 - 1 = 0.00655022 = 0.655022 %
```

The profit on 1000 shares from Dec 31st to Jan 10th is `$4600 * -0.00434783 = -$20`

The profit on 800 shares from Jan 10th to Feb 28th is zero.

The profit on 800 shares from Feb 28th to March 16th is

```
800 * $4.58 * 0.00655022 = $24
```

So the year to date profit is $4.

Comment: Amazing thank you very much Chris. Really Appreciate it . But got one last question. For all your calculation the Inital price of 800 @$4.5 and 200@$4.55 price is not used. For YTD PnL  Can we use the initial price to calculate the PnL for 12/10/2010 till 12/31/2010 and add it along each month?

Comment: @MarkAustin I have added it in.  Usually year to date would be understood to run from Dec 31st, for comparison with other stocks.  For example: https://www.google.com/search?q=year+to+date . The information prior to Dec 31st may have been thrown in to confuse you, but you can cover the bases by stating both returns and explaining the difference.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much. On your YtD calculation. I thought it would be easier to calculate the price on March 16th minus Dec 31st . i.e. (4.61-4.6)*1000 = 10 Is this same as what you did?

Comment: @MarkAustin `4.60*((4.58/4.60)*(4.61/4.58) - 1)` does simplify to `4.61 - 4.60`.  However, in going the long way round the returns for the various periods are also calculated.  The returns are often useful to know.

Comment: if i have a short position instead of long position then the signs would change right?

Comment: Just one more question. Say for example I sold 200 shares on Jan10th 2011 for $4.58 per share. what would be the YTD PnL now ? Thank you

Comment: @Mark I have added the calculation.  It illustrates why it's useful to calculate the returns.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much chris. Much appreciated.

Comment: : Just got one more question. I want to convert the YTD to Swiss Franc .I have on 12/31/2010 the CHF/USD is 1.02 , on 02/28/2011 the CHF/USD is 1.01 and on 03/16/2011 the CHF/USD is 1.015 . Can you simple divide the end result in USD by the current FX rate which is 1.015. So for Calendar year to date the PnL would be 10/1.015 = 9.52?

Comment: @MarkAustin You should convert all the prices according to the FX rate at the various dates, then do the return and profit calculations with the FX'd prices.

Comment: Thank you chris. But the problem is when i convert all prices and calculate i get 46 which doesn't make sense. YTD in USD is $10 but YTD in CHF is 46?

Comment: @MarkAustin Converting every dollar figure to Swiss Franc: `YTD = 1000*(4.60/
   1.02)*(((4.58/1.01)/(4.60/1.02))*((4.61/1.015)/(4.58/1.01)) - 1) = CHF 32.068`  You can check by changing every exchange rate figure to 1 and the result reverts to 10 (dollars).

Comment: @MarkAustin That is the same as saying you invest CHF at $4.60 so pay `$4.60/1.02 = CHF 4.5098` then sell at $4.61 and convert back `$4.61/1.015 = CHF 4.54187`, which is a return of 0.71107%. For 1000 shares at CHF 4.5098: `1000 * 4.5098 * 0.0071107 = 32.068`